# WPF UserControl Dependency Property not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-controls

In a WPF project (code below) I have a `UserControl` of type `MyUserControl` with a dependency property, called `MyOrientation` of type `Orientation`.

On the `MainWindow` I have 2 instances of `MyUserControl`, where via XAML I set the `Orientation` property on one to be `Horizontal` and the other instance to be `Vertical`.

I have made the `MyOrientation` property a DP as I want the ability to set it directly in XAML as in this example or using a binding.

My problem is that when I run the project both instances of the UserControl show up with the Orientation = Horizontal?

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Many thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

MYUSERCONTROLVIEWMODEL:

```
public class MyUserControlViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Orientation _myOrientation;
    public Orientation MyOrientation
    {
        get { return _myOrientation; }
        set
        {
            if (_myOrientation == value)
                return;
            _myOrientation = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

MYUSERCONTROL.XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestUserControlDPProblem.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestUserControlDPProblem"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid x:Name="root">

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:MyUserControlViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="{Binding MyOrientation}">
        <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>There</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MYUSERCONTROL CODE BEHIND:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    MyUserControlViewModel _vm;

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _vm = root.DataContext as MyUserControlViewModel;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyOrientationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyOrientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(MyUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Vertical, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnMyOrientationChanged)));

    private static void OnMyOrientationChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myUserControl = o as MyUserControl;
        myUserControl?.OnMyOrientationChanged((Orientation)e.OldValue, (Orientation)e.NewValue);
    }

    protected virtual void OnMyOrientationChanged(Orientation oldValue, Orientation newValue)
    {
        _vm.MyOrientation = newValue;
    }
    public Orientation MyOrientation
    {
        get
        {
            return (Orientation)GetValue(MyOrientationProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyOrientationProperty, value);
        }
    }

}
```

MAINWINDOW.XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TestUserControlDPProblem.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestUserControlDPProblem"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyUserControl Margin="10" MyOrientation="Horizontal"/>
        <local:MyUserControl Margin="10" MyOrientation="Vertical"/>
    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "internal" view model of the UserControl makes no sense and should not be there. You should instead bind directly to the dependency property by means of a RelativeSource or ElementName Binding:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="{Binding MyOrientation,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

You wouldn't even need the PropertyChangedCallback:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyOrientationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(MyOrientation), typeof(Orientation), typeof(MyUserControl), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Vertical));

    public Orientation MyOrientation
    {
        get { return (Orientation)GetValue(MyOrientationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyOrientationProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Your changes indeed do the job. I would like to say the 'internal' view model was implemented to give the UserControl the ability to have it's own DataContext. Or, that was the intention anyway. I am still confused why my code didn't work however.

Comment: You should never do that. The DataContext should only be inherited from the parent element of the UserControl, and the UserControl should only expose dependency properties that are bound to properties of the view model object in the inherited DataContext. These Binding should not be declared "internally" in the UserControl's XAML, but when the control is used somewhere.

Comment: I was trying to follow the advice given in Brian Noyes' Blog here: http://briannoyesblog.azurewebsites.net/2015/09/19/using-mvvm-in-a-reusable-usercontrol/

Comment: I didn't read it, but in case it's advising that a UserControl should have an own view model, it's plain wrong. Don't believe everything on the internet. There are tons of blogs written by "experts" that show UserControls with private view models. The people reading those blogs tend to end up here, asking why their bindings to the dependency properties of their UserControls aren't working.